# TypeScript transitively imports ES libraries

Tags: typescript

I want to make sure that my code doesn't use newer library features than ES6. Consequently, my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

This works as expected, and calls like `Object.fromEntries` are flagged as errors.

Sadly, as soon as I install some dev dependency that depends on `@types/node`, e.g. a Rollup plugin, TypeScript picks up on the following declaration in `node_modules/@types/node`:

```
/// <reference lib="es2018" />
```

(file `node_modules/@types/node/ts3.7/base.d.ts`).

Suddendly, `Object.fromEntries` is not flagged anymore because – despite my config in `tsconfig.json` – TypeScript now loads the ES2018 library.

Is there any way I can avoid that?

Comment: Seems like this is a known bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33111 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37775